# Add URL Parameter To Htaccess Redirect ErrorDocument

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my website, when the user navigates to an invalid url I still want to display what he was looking for but when I redirect to my `error.php` via `.htacces` the faulty URL is lost.

I'm using this to redirect (.htaccess):

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/error.php
```

What I want insead is to add the faulty URL to the end of the redirect as URL parameter.

For examplewhen the user navigates to this URL `https:www.mywebsite.com/this-does-not-exist` I want that to reflect in my error.php as well and add the last part as URL paramater. The URL should then look like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/error.php?url=this-does-not-exist
```

I already tried doing `ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/error.php?url=$1` and I also tried `ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/error.php [L]` both versions did not give me the desired result.

How can I add the faulty url to the ErrorDocument redirect as url parameter in `htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the document root and not the host in your `.htaccess` IE:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Then in your PHP script `error.php` you can get the current URL simply by using

```
$url = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
echo "The page $url you are trying to reach doesn't exist!";
```

All the while KEEPING the current URL

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/this-does-not-exist
```

displayed in the URL bar.